# Save matplotlib as image so it can be resized later

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a graph using Python matplotlib, saving and displaying it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Not the real values, I have about 100,000
p = [1,2,3]
t = [1,2,3]

plt.plot(t, p)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::10000])
plt.savefig('/path/filename.svg', format='svg')
plt.show()
```

I would like to save the image as a vector (without losing data) so that later I can open the image, drag it to be wider etc, like is possible when the code calls `.show()`.

I thought this would be possible saving as a .svg, but when I open the saved image using the default Ubuntu image viewer, it's a fixed image (all my points squished together on a small graph).

Is it possible to save the graph as an image so the image can resized etc, like when calling `show()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plt.savefig` and enter vectorized image format extension into its `format` keyword argument.  But from the context it seems that what you want is to re-load the image with matplotlib interactive environment like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZFct.png) rather than displaying the image only.

Using `pickle` to save your `ax` instance as binary file might help.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

p = [1,2,3]
t = [1,2,3]
plt.plot(t, p)
ax = plt.gca()

with open('image', 'wb') as f: #'wb' is to create new file and write
    pickle.dump(ax, f)
```

With above script you would see a file named as 'image' created in the directory you executed above script. The file is not in any known image formats but `ax` instance you created, which is serialized by `pickle`.

You can then use `pickle.load` function in other context to load the file and interact with it using matplotlib repeatedly.

```py
# In different script

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

with open('image', 'rb') as f: #'rb' is to specify read-only
    loaded_ax = pickle.load(f)

plt.show()
```